# Why won't the form (or control) keydown event fire when a form with a control in it has focus?

Tags: winforms

I just have a form, and using this.Controls.Add in the form I have added a container control which basically fills the whole background area of the form (and contains many other controls like datagridviews, comboboxes etc), so I can't click off of it.

Now, in the form class, I want to add some keyboard shortcuts.. Like, F5 saves my work for instance. Anyway, I have hooked up to the control's keydown even in the form class, but, it doesn't seem to fire!

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably have helped if you would have described which control you were adding.  You are most likely adding a control that is trying to read the keyboard events.  For the form to still get those events, change this property:

```
this.KeyPreview = True;
```